# How to define common directives in controllerAs syntax?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, directive

I was reading [Digging into Angular's "Controller as" syntax](https://toddmotto.com/digging-into-angulars-controller-as-syntax/) article. It shows below snippet to use "Controller as" syntax in directive.

```
app.directive('myDirective', function () {
  return {
    restrict: 'EA',
    replace: true,
    scope: true,
    template: [].join(''),
    controllerAs: '', // woohoo, nice and easy!
    controller: function () {}, // we'll instantiate this controller "as" the above name
    link: function () {}
  };
});
```

Here I have to set controller name `controller` property. Now if I want to define common directive which I want to use in multiple controllers, how can I do it?

**Edit 1:**

I am posting the code about what I want to achieve. In view, there is a input tag for file and when file is selected I want it's name and content type. I will use change event of input tag. I don't know how can I pass the file object to my vm. I want to use that directive which uses change event to get info about file in multiple controllers.

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" ng-app="myApp">
<head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.8/angular.js"></script>
    <script src="/myCtrl.js"></script>
</head>

<body ng-controller="MyController as vm">
    <input name="file" type="file" file />
    <input type="button" ng-click="vm.upload(vm.file);" value="Upload" />
</body>
</html>
```

myCtrl.js

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);

app.controller('MyController', MyController);

MyController.$inject = ['$http'];

function MyController($http) {
    var vm = this;

    vm.file = null;
    vm.upload = function(file) {
      $http.post('/upload', { filename: file.name, contentType: file.type })
        .success(function(resp) {
            console.log(resp);
        })
        .error(function(resp) {
            console.log(resp);
        });
    }
}

app.directive('file', function() {
  return {
    restrict: 'AE',
    scope: true,
    controllerAs: 'vm',
    link: function(scope, el, attrs){
      el.bind('change', function(event){
        var files = event.target.files;
        var file = files[0];

        // What to write here to pass file object into vm ?

        // Below line is for that controller design which uses $scope service. But I am using controllerAs syntax
        // scope.file = file;
        // scope.$apply();
      });
    }
  };
});
```

Answer (score 0):

very good article about it please read http://blog.thoughtram.io/angularjs/2015/01/02/exploring-angular-1.3-bindToController.html

Answer (score 0):

If you want to share the multiple controller with single directive definition,then defined the directive with no controller (optional).

> **IMP** : define the directive with `scope: true` or leave it with `default scope` but don't define `isolated scope`.
>   This will allow the directive to inherit the method and property defined in parent controller.

And place the directive inside `ng-controller` directive in template.

controller 1:

```
<div ng-controller='ctrl1">

  <my-directive></my-directive>
<div>
```

controller 2 :

```
<div ng-controller='ctrl2">

  <my-directive></my-directive>
<div>
```

nth the way.

EDIT1 :

In controller (`MyController`) : you can use [`$broadcast`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope)

```
vm.upload = function(fileObj){

    $rootScope.$broadcast('sending-file-object',{data:fileObj})
}
```

Will receive in all others controller using [`$on`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope) ,

```
$scope.$on('sending-file-object',function(event,data){
  console.log(data) // here you get data;
})
```